# Is it safe to temporarily give away ownership of the contents of a mutable borrow in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

Is a function that modifies a `&mut T` in place by a function `FnOnce(T) -> T` safe to have in rust, or can it lead to undefined behavior? Is it included in the standard library somewhere, or a well-known crate?

If you additionally assume `T: Default`, that looks like

```
fn modify<T, F: FnOnce(T) -> T>(x: &mut T, f: F) -> ()
where
    T: Default
{
    let val = std::mem::take(x);
    let val = f(val);
    *x = val;
}
```

(See also
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f015812bac6f527fe663fe4e0b7a3188)

My question is about doing the same but dropping the `where T: Default` clause (and no `T: Clone` either). This requires a different implementation, since you can't use `std::mem::take`.
I'm not sure how to implement the unconstrained version, but it should be possible using unsafe Rust.

I'm learning Rust from a background of linear types and sub-structural logic. Rust's mutable borrow seems very similar to moving a resource in and then back out of a function, but I don't know if it is actually safe to take temporary ownership of the contents of a mutable borrow like this.

Comment: You almost certainly want to look into the [`replace_with` crate](https://crates.io/crates/replace_with), which offers that functionality while taclking the issue of panic-safety.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe, and there are even crates for that (can't find them now).

HOWEVER.

When writing unsafe code, you have to be very careful. If you don't know exactly what you're doing, it can easily lead to UB.

Here, for example, there is something you maybe haven't thought of: panic safety.

Suppose we implement that trivially:

```rust
pub fn modify<T, F: FnOnce(T) -> T>(v: &mut T, f: F) {
    let prev = unsafe { std::ptr::read(v) };
    let new = f(prev);
    unsafe { std::ptr::write(v, new) };
}
```

Trivially right.

Or is it?

```rust
fn main() {
    struct MyStruct(pub i32);
    impl Drop for MyStruct {
        fn drop(&mut self) {
            println!("MyStruct({}) dropped", self.0);
        }
    }

    let mut v = MyStruct(123);
    std::panic::catch_unwind(std::panic::AssertUnwindSafe(|| {
        modify(&mut v, |_prev| {
            // `prev` is dropped here.
            panic!("Haha, evil panic!");
        })
    }))
    .unwrap_err();
    v.0 = 456; // Writing to an uninitialized memory!
               // `v` is dropped here, double drop!
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f7312a8be70cd43cf5cf7a9816be56a

I used a custom type that its destructor does nothing but to print, but imagine what could happen if this was a `Vec` that freed the memory and we were writing into freed memory (then, as a bonus, get a double-free).

It is correct, like @Kendas said, that when there are no interruption point it is valid to leave memory in an uninitialized state in Rust. The problem is, that much more places than you wish are actually interruption points. In fact, when writing unsafe code, you have to consider *any call to external code* (i.e. not yours code neither code that you trust to not do bad things, for example std) to be an interruption point.

Unsafe code is hard. Better stay in the safe land.

**Edit:** You may wonder what the `AssertUnwindSafe` is. Maybe you even tried to remove it and noticed it doesn't compiler. Well, `UnwindSafe` is a protection against this, and `AssertUnwindSafe` is a way to bypass the protection.

You may ask, what's the point? The point is, this protection is really not accurate. So much not accurate, that bypassing it does not even require unsafe. But it still exists, so we have a lower chance of accidental UB.

It doesn't matter to you as the writer of the API - you should act like this protection doesn't exist, *because* it is safe to bypass it and easy to do so by mistake. The Rust standard library itself had bugs like that in the past ([#86443](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86443), [#81740](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/81740), ... - It is not an accident that they're both in the same code - those issues tend to appear in chunks. But there're more).

Answer (score -1):

Well, you are replacing the contents of the borrowed memory location with the default value. This would mean that the memory is indeed correct at every point. So there should not be any undefined behavior.

Basically from the perspective of the mutable reference `x`, you are mutating it to the default value, then mutating it again to a different new value.

In general, if there is a chance of undefined behavior, you will need to use the `unsafe` keyword. Or somebody has made a mistake while using the `unsafe` keyword further down the stack. It is relatively rare for these things to happen in the standard library.

Go ahead and look at the safety remarks in the code if you must: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/mem/mod.rs.html#756

Comment: I understand that if `T: Default`, this function is safe (as the compiler demonstrates by not requiring the `unsafe` keyword. My question is about a version where you do *not* have `T: Default`.